# Legend box series title, how to highlight other chart series in LightningChart?

Tags: wpf, graph, charts, mouseevent, legend

I can see that when moving mouse over series titles in ViewXY's LegendBox, the series gets highlighted.

I'm using WPF chart. I have several series that I'd like to highlight in the same time.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

LegendBox class has **SeriesTitle*** events. You can utilize it pretty much like this:

```
m_chart.BeginUpdate();


ViewXY viewXY = m_chart.ViewXY;
viewXY.XAxes[0].ValueType = AxisValueType.Number; 

int seriesCount = 10; 

//Create series that will highlight the other series 

for (int i = 0; i < seriesCount; i++)
{
   PointLineSeries s = new PointLineSeries(viewXY, viewXY.XAxes[0], viewXY.YAxes[0]);
   s.LineStyle.Color = DefaultColors.SeriesForBlackBackgroundWpf[i]; 
   s.Points = GenerateSomeRandomData((i+1) * 20);
   s.Title.Text = "Series " + i.ToString(); 
   viewXY.PointLineSeries.Add(s);
}
viewXY.LegendBox.MoveFromSeriesTitle = false;
viewXY.LegendBox.SeriesTitleMouseClick += LegendBox_SeriesTitleMouseClick;
viewXY.LegendBox.Layout = LegendBoxLayout.Vertical; 

m_chart.EndUpdate();
```

and defining the event handler like this:

```
void LegendBox_SeriesTitleMouseClick(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        m_chart.BeginUpdate(); 

        foreach (PointLineSeries s in m_chart.ViewXY.PointLineSeries)
        {
            s.SetHighlight();

            //s.RemoveHighlight(); //To remove highlight, use this 
        }
        m_chart.EndUpdate(); 
    }
```

Then click on any series title, and all the series get highlighted. Based on series.MouseHighlight property setting, it changes to brighter thick line, animated color from bright to dark, or keeps original color.

[image: All the series get highlighted when you move mouse over any series title in the Legend box]

Hopefully this helps :-)

Comment: Kudos man! That works. But if I only want to show some of these series in the legend, and hide the rest, how to do that?

Comment: You can do that by setting series.ShowInLegendBox = false for all the series you don't want to see in the legend box.

Comment: Thanks very helpful answer.